Should I change my primary supervisor?
I'm in my second year and 8 months into my PhD, I am supposed to complete one  SLR and two empirical studies to successfully complete the PhD. I am supposed to be working on a pre-existing database that has the data I need. To access it you need to pre-register your studies (which I've done in 2022). I also have the ethics approval from my uni.
The issue is my primary supervisor will not let me either contact the team to get the database nor would she let me look into what data I have! I feel extremely exhausted by this. I have tried to mediate and explain and request the data for my analysis but every time I do I am asked to wait. When I raised the issue finally to the higher-ups, I found out later from our faculty research coordinator that my primary supervisor had falsely told them that I already have the database and that I am doing quality checks on them. Which is completely untrue, I showed all the evidence to the research coordinator but they seemed to continue to advice me to try and work with my primary supervisor to finish the PhD off or downgrade to a masters.
I don't understand why I should do this? Especially when there hasn't been any issue with my progress. So I looked up the university policy and it clearly states that I can change supervisors if I wanted to. So I am inclined to do that instead of continuously being gaslit into believing that I'm doing well when I truly haven't done anything for my PhD other than the systematics review (which is not complete either btw).

related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26398/can-someone-change-phd-supervisor-without-changing-research-direction

related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/69051/changing-current-supervisor

You need to have an open discussion with your supervisor. Do you have any co-supervisor? If you do, you could seek help from them. The purpose is to get things clear and know the specific reason why your supervisor stops you by touching the data. Direct communication to your supervisor and focusing on the fact is the best solution at the moment.
Of course, you can move to another supervisor as the last option if you believe that you two cannot work together any longer. Make sure that you can find a better supervisor who could better support and will to take you from your current supervisor. You may not be able to continue for your current work due to IP issues. You need to check with the graduate research office to clean it.
Do not take any rush decision or broadcast your story to anyone who should not be involved in your case. You may not know the whole story, and you may need to survive in the same community in the future.
